# Import Xamarin Keystore - System.AggregateException

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, keytool

I have a .pfx file that I used to generated a keystore file using the following command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore TestCodeSign.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12
```

Keytool came back and said 'The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format..."

So I ran the suggested command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\USERNAME\.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\USERNAME\.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12
```

I now have the backed up copy, '.old' and the new .keystore file.

In Visual Studio, I create an archive for the release version of my app.  Then I click Distribute->Google Play and then hit Import to locate the .keystore file.

[image]

But when I import, I get a useless error.  I checked the Xamarin.Diagnostics output, I can see another error:

```
[E:keytool]:              ImportKey - System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidSdkToolException: Importing keystore C:\\Temp\\TestCodeSign.keystore to C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Xamarin\\Mono for Android\\Keystore\\A\\A.keystore...
```

And that is it.  How can I import an existing pfx file into a keystore and then use that keystore to sign the application for distribution to Google Play?

Comment: I think you are giving it an incorrect ALIAS!

Comment: @FreakyAli  Correct!  The name in the keystore after doing a -list was some random string of characters.  After renaming the alias, I was able to do the full deployment!

Comment: That's great I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generate a .keytore file to test. When I import with the wrong password or alias, it would throw the same error. Please check your password and alias.
[image]

If you do not make sure about the alias and password, you could create a new .ketstore file to import for test.

For more details about generate a .keystore file, please refer to the MS docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows